# Create a column and use previous value of created column in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a table where I want to calculate average price of bought assets, values is like this:

| RowNumber | price | volume | prevNetVolume |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 100 | 0 |
| 2 | 200 | 100 | 100 |
| 3 | 100 | 100 | 200 |
| 4 | 100 | -100 | 300 |
| 5 | 200 | 100 | 200 |
| 6 | 100 | -200 | 300 |
| 7 | 300 | 100 | 100 |

price and volume is data of current purchase and prevNetVolume is sum of all buy and sell volumes of previous rows. I want to calculate average price for each row. This is the average price formula:

```
if (volume > 0)
{
    // it is a buy transaction
    averagePrice = (price * volume) + (prevNetVolume * prevAveragePrice))/(prevNetVolume + volme)
} 
else
{
    // it is a sell transaction
    averagePrice = prevAveragePrice;
}
```

and **prevAveragePrice** is **averagePrice**  of previous row, but as I don't have that column yet, I don't know how to create and access its previous value at the same time. At the end we must have a table like this:

| RowNumber | price | volume | prevNetVolume | averagePrice |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 100 | 0 | 100 |
| 2 | 200 | 100 | 100 | 150 |
| 3 | 100 | 100 | 200 | 133.33 |
| 4 | 100 | -100 | 300 | 133.33 |
| 5 | 200 | 100 | 200 | 155.55 |
| 6 | 100 | -200 | 300 | 155.55 |
| 7 | 300 | 100 | 100 | 227.77 |

How can I create this column in SQL?

I tried to solve the problem using a temp table, a while loop and lag function, first I added averagePrice as 0:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Transaction2') is not null
DROP TABLE #Transaction2
SELECT
    *
    , 0 AS averagePrice
    ,ISNULL((SELECT SUM(b.Volume) FROM Table1 b WHERE Table1.RowNumber > b.RowNumber ),0) AS prevNetVolume
    
 INTO #Transaction2
FROM Table1

DECLARE @count INT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #Transaction2)
DECLARE @counter INT =1;
WHILE @counter <@count
BEGIN

UPDATE #Transaction2
    SET averagePrice = (SELECT ((Volume*price)+(ISNULL(LAG(averagePrice) OVER (ORDER BY RowNumber),0)*prevNetVolume))/(prevNetVolume + Volume) )
    WHERE @counter = RowNumber
    SET @counter += 1
END

SELECT * FROM #Transaction2
```

the problem here is the **LAG** inside the update, does not correctly read the updated value of averagePrice of previous row. is there a way to get the updated value? here is the fiddle: [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/W3POX1Fc)

Comment: You are looking for CASE WHEN ... THEN. Please consult your vendor's documentation and then [tell us](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) what technical solution you settled on, citing relevant documentation URL(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
DECLARE @count INT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_table)
DECLARE @counter INT = 1;
DECLARE @prevAvgPrice FLOAT = 0;

WHILE @counter <= @count
BEGIN
    DECLARE @price FLOAT = (SELECT price FROM my_table WHERE RowNumber = @counter)
    DECLARE @volume FLOAT = (SELECT volume FROM my_table WHERE RowNumber = @counter)
    DECLARE @prevNetVolume FLOAT = (SELECT prevNetVolume FROM my_table WHERE RowNumber = @counter)
    
    DECLARE @averagePrice FLOAT;
    
    IF @volume > 0
    BEGIN
        -- it is a buy transaction
        SET @averagePrice = ((@price * @volume) + (@prevNetVolume * @prevAvgPrice)) / (@prevNetVolume + @volume)
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        -- it is a sell transaction
        SET @averagePrice = @prevAvgPrice;
    END
    
    -- update the current row with the calculated average price
    UPDATE my_table SET averagePrice = @averagePrice WHERE RowNumber = @counter;
    
    -- update the previous average price for the next iteration
    SET @prevAvgPrice = @averagePrice;
    
    SET @counter += 1;
END

SELECT * FROM my_table;
```

here is the fiddle: [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/XZ88DRaQ)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `CASE WHEN` clause

```
 CASE WHEN (volume > 0) THEN
     (price * volume) + (prevNetVolume * prevAveragePrice))/(prevNetVolume + volme)
else
      prevAveragePrice
END averagePrice
```

As you asked only for how to get the values, you can use window funcz´tion to get the SUM and AVG

AND the mentioned CTE to get the previous calculated values

As you ddidn't specify the databse system you are using i choose SQL server, but alomos all databases systems suport CTE and window functions

```
WITH CTE AS (SELECT
[RowNumber], [price], [volume],
SUM([volume]) OVER( ORDER BY [RowNumber])  NetVolume
  ,AVG([price]) OVER( ORDER BY [RowNumber]) avg_price
FROM table1)
SELECT
[RowNumber], [price], [volume],
  CASE WHEN LAG(NetVolume) OVER (ORDER BY [RowNumber]) IS NULL THEN 0
  ELSE LAG(NetVolume) OVER (ORDER BY [RowNumber]) END prevNetVolume,
avg_price
FROM CTE
```

| RowNumber | price | volume | prevNetVolume | avg_price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100.00 | 100 | 0 | 100.000000 |
| 2 | 200.00 | 100 | 100 | 150.000000 |
| 3 | 100.00 | 100 | 200 | 133.333333 |
| 4 | 100.00 | -100 | 300 | 125.000000 |
| 5 | 200.00 | 100 | 200 | 140.000000 |
| 6 | 100.00 | -200 | 300 | 133.333333 |
| 7 | 300.00 | 100 | 100 | 157.142857 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/vWtIZPeb)

adding your formula, the numbers will end  up

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    ([RowNumber] int, [price] DECIMAL (10,2), [volume] int)
;
    
INSERT INTO Table1
    ([RowNumber], [price], [volume])
VALUES
    (1, 100, 100),
    (2, 200, 100),
    (3, 100, 100),
    (4, 100, -100),
    (5, 200, 100),
    (6, 100, -200),
    (7, 300, 100)
;
```

```
7 rows affected
```

```
WITH CTE AS (SELECT
[RowNumber], [price], [volume],
SUM([volume]) OVER( ORDER BY [RowNumber])  NetVolume
  ,AVG([price]) OVER( ORDER BY [RowNumber]) avg_price
FROM table1),
cte2 as
(SELECT
[RowNumber], [price], [volume],
  CASE WHEN LAG(NetVolume) OVER (ORDER BY [RowNumber]) IS NULL THEN 0
  ELSE LAG(NetVolume) OVER (ORDER BY [RowNumber]) END prevNetVolume,
  CASE WHEN LAG(avg_price) OVER (ORDER BY [RowNumber]) IS NULL THEN 0
  ELSE LAG(avg_price) OVER (ORDER BY [RowNumber]) END prevAveragePrice
  FROM CTE)
SELECT
  [RowNumber], [price], [volume],
  prevNetVolume,
 CASE WHEN (volume > 0) THEN
     ((price * volume) + (prevNetVolume * prevAveragePrice))/(prevNetVolume + volume)
else
      prevAveragePrice
END averagePrice
FROM CTE2
```

| RowNumber | price | volume | prevNetVolume | averagePrice |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100.00 | 100 | 0 | 100.000000 |
| 2 | 200.00 | 100 | 100 | 150.000000 |
| 3 | 100.00 | 100 | 200 | 133.333333 |
| 4 | 100.00 | -100 | 300 | 133.333333 |
| 5 | 200.00 | 100 | 200 | 150.000000 |
| 6 | 100.00 | -200 | 300 | 140.000000 |
| 7 | 300.00 | 100 | 100 | 216.666666 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/6oylO5Si)

Comment: currently there is no averagePrice or prevAveragePrice columns in the table so we can not use them, we must create them using the formula and store it in the table

Comment: you need a CTE which gets you the wanted columns values, but that was not what you asked for.

Comment: I edited the question to clarify what I need

Comment: i add a version for SQL SERVER, but you can use adapt it to any rdms

Comment: thanks, it does not use the formula, and just calculates averages of prices. it must calculate weighted average using the formula I wrote.

Comment: even when i use your formula used like the fist code i write the numbers you write doesn't end up

Comment: I suggested an edit fot the second formula , it's close this time, but problem arises the row after when we reach a sell transaction (negative colume)

Comment: you cam add more queries to then fiddle as fas as i can see the numbers are correct

Comment: I looked into my table again, there was a mistake, I corrected it, but your answer is not correct yet, and the problem is you are using a avg_price from CTE that is not correct itself.

Comment: your math isn't logiocal an avrage goes over a numbe rof values, as yu didn't statem what  numbers you expect, the avergae over all row till the row that is currently calculatingm if you only want average betweeen 3 or 4 values you have to clarify it

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT m1.*,
    COALESCE(LAG(volume) OVER (ORDER BY RowNumber),0) as PerviousVolume,
    volume * price  as TotalPriceForThisLine,
    SUM(volume * price) OVER (order by RowNumber) as CumulativeTotalPrice,
    SUM(volume) OVER (order by RowNumber) as CumulatieveVolume,
    SUM(volume * price) OVER (order by RowNumber) / 
      SUM(volume) OVER (order by RowNumber) as AveragePrice
  
FROM mytable m1
```

| RowNumber | price | volume | prevNetVolume | PerviousVolume | TotalPriceForThisLine | CumulativeTotalPrice | CumulatieveVolume | AveragePrice |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 100 | 0 | 0 | 10000 | 10000 | 100 | 100.0000 |
| 2 | 200 | 100 | 100 | 100 | 20000 | 30000 | 200 | 150.0000 |
| 3 | 100 | 100 | 200 | 100 | 10000 | 40000 | 300 | 133.3333 |
| 4 | 100 | -100 | 300 | 100 | -10000 | 30000 | 200 | 150.0000 |
| 5 | 200 | 100 | 200 | -100 | 20000 | 50000 | 300 | 166.6667 |
| 6 | 100 | -200 | 300 | 100 | -20000 | 30000 | 100 | 300.0000 |
| 7 | 300 | 100 | 100 | -200 | 30000 | 60000 | 200 | 300.0000 |

NOTE: My Average price is different than yours, can you find the error that I, oy you, made  ?

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/osEvLjPp)

Comment: thank you, but the problem with this solution is, it ignores the condition where transaction is a sell ( negative volume) it must not update the average price, and average price is the average price of the previous row.

Comment: I think, when ignoring the sells, you should also leave out the buys related to the sells, when calculating the average ?  (But that's just my opinion )